# Should I fill up the US tourist visa form separately?

Tags: usa, tourist-visas, applications

My mom and I are planning to apply for a US TOURIST VISA (B1/B2) and my mom is going to pay for our trip.
My question is: do I need to fill up the DS160 form separately?
She filled up the form and she put my name in accompanying person.

Now I am just confused if I should fill up the form separately or not.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, every individual submits a stand-alone application form regardless.

2 persons will submit 2 forms and pay 2 times even if they are going together.